# Function is not returning data back to my array

Tags: javascript, node.js, function

im having a problem with my function Mrequest,the problem is that data like id and year are not add to de array. I know is a problem with the function but i just cant solve it.
any idea of what could i change so my array result get the ID and the YEAR

```
function getContent() {
            var result = [];

            async.series([
              getDb,
              getInfos

            ]);


            function getDb(done) {
              //posta
              var query = "SELECT title , launch_year FROM content WHERE content_genre_id=1 && content_type_id!=2 LIMIT 2;"
              mysqlConnection.query(query, function(err, data) {
                result = data;
                async.each(result, getPelicula, done);
              });
            }


              function Mrequest(pagina, callback){
                request({
                  url: pagina,
                  method: "GET",
                  json: true,
                }, callback);

              }
      function getPelicula(pelicula, donePelicula) {
              var peli = pelicula.title;


              var pagina = "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?query=" + peli + "&api_key=3e2709c4c051b07326f1080b90e283b4&language=en=ES&page=1&include_adult=false"
              setTimeout(function() {
                Mrequest(pagina, function(error, res, body) {
                  if (error) {
                    console.log("error", error);
                  } else {
                    var control = body.results.length;
                    if (control > 0) {
                      var year_base = pelicula.launch_year;

                      var id = body.results[0].id;
                      var year = body.results[0].release_date;
                      var d = new Date(year);
                      var year_solo = d.getFullYear();
                      console.log(pelicula);
                      console.log("id",id);
                      console.log("year",year);
                      console.log("year",year_solo);
                      if (year_base == year_solo) {

                        pelicula.id = id;
                        pelicula.year_pagina = year_solo;
                      } else {

                        pelicula.id = -1;
                        pelicula.year_pagina = null;
                      }
                    }
                  }
                });
              }, result.indexOf(pelicula) * 3000);

              donePelicula();
            }
    getContent();
    }
```

Comment: first thing, I see that you are calling getContent inside getContent method. It is either going to be an infinite loop or never called?

Comment: its work fine, im not getting infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't look like you are making the request because getContent is being called from within itself